# Certificate Chain with AWS ELB & GoDaddy Certs

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, godaddy

I'm trying to setup SSL on my AWS ELB, but I am thus far unable to figure out what goes into the "Certificate Chain" field. I receive the following error:

> Unable to validate certificate chain. The certificate chain must start
>   with the immediate signing certificate, followed by any intermediaries
>   in order. The index within the chain of the invalid certificate is: -1

I have my private key & certificate in PEM format and uploaded. If I use these without the "optional" chain, it works untrusted. I have been poking around, trying to find an answer on what to put into the field, and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/568824) suggests downloading the [gd_bundle-g2.crt](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository) - I have done this and converted it into PEM by running `openssl x509 -inform PEM -in gd_bundle-g2.crt` but the error remains. When I downloaded my certificate from GoDaddy, I was given a ZIP with my SSL certificate along with `gdig2.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. I have tried using these files in various combinations, and alone, but again, nothing.

What certificates go into the Certificate Chain, in what order, and in what format?

Answer (score 7):

So the problem was several mistakes along the way for me. First, I took the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` section from the PEM generated from my `keytool` keystore. Second, I was trying to convert the `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` file - it already contained exactly what I needed to use.

To start from the beginning - I used Digicert's [Java Keytool](https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/keytool.htm) to generate my commands to get my keystore and CSR using `keytool`. From there, I got a wildcard SSL certificate through GoDaddy and downloaded my certificate which was in a ZIP file along with `gdig.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. After this, I follwed to steps to get the private key from my keystore following this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656559/372743). However, the `foo.pem` file from this command required [one more command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165198/372743), `openssl rsa -in foo.pem -out foo.rsa` to get the final form accepted by the AWS panel.

Now to fill in the SSL form on AWS:

- Private Key: The contents of the `foo.rsa` file from the previous step.
- Public Key Certificate: The contents of the `<your_cert>.crt` file provided by GoDaddy
- Certificate Chain: The contents of the `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` file provided by GoDaddy

This has given me a successful SSL certificate setup for my AWS ELB, with the proper certificate path, giving me a trusted certificate.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure what to use as the chain in amazon , simply put the text from the crt file as you said and it worked .

Comment: Yep, gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt works for me

Comment: goddady `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` certs can be found here https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

Answer (score 1):

It's not a trivial process, and the documentation isn't great.

This version of the [process using Gandi.net SSL certificates](http://lexical.scopely.com/2015/03/11/uploading-an-ssl-cert-from-gandi-net-to-iam/) might help you work though it, it's much better than the official docs

http://lexical.scopely.com/2015/03/11/uploading-an-ssl-cert-from-gandi-net-to-iam/

Comment: Thought not directly helpful, it gave me some ideas to try that led me to the correct answer. Thanks for the links!

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include the relevant parts in the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that the intermediate certificates are not specific to your domain or certificate.  So, every certificate issued that is like yours, has the exact same intermediate certificates.

You can think of them a bit like the routing number on your checks.  The routing number is needed, but really says more about your bank than it does about you.  Your account number, or your certificate in this case, is what is unique to you.

Because of the generic nature of the intermediate certificates there are websites like this one:

https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/ssl-intermediate-and-root-ca-bundle

That have all of the intermediate certificates pre-bundled (and in the correct order) for different certificate issuers.